# How to Configure OAuth2 Authentication for Apache Kafka Cluster using AZURE AD

Tags: apache-kafka, active-directory, azure-active-directory

due to the lack of INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT in azure AD, I am unable to validate the token.

How to validate the Azure Access token in Java?

Comment: May I know if you still  have any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the ADAL or the MSAL SDK will take care of it. But, you can still manually validate the access token you get. Here is the official tutorial: [Validating tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).

In summary, there would be 3 steps:

1. Get the `kid` in token header, and the `tid` in token payload.
2. Get all sign keys from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid_here}/discovery/v2.0/keys`, and find the key with `kid`
3. `x5c` in the key is the public certificate. You can use it to verify the signature of a token.

Comment: @VinodKkumar Create an easy sample. You may get it from [ValidateToken](https://github.com/AI-EVO/ValidateToken)

Comment: By the way, the sample just verifies the signature. You may also need to validate all other necessary claims. For example, validate `exp` claim to ensure the token is not expired.